# How do you create an arbitrary throwaway lambda expression in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, dry

Is there a better Functional Interface type to hold this lambda expression? And is there a clean way to replace the loops with streams? Looking for a way to do this with more expressive code.

The problem is to analyze a 2D grid (grid) and save the results in a simple value-holding class (results). One must walk up, down, left, and right along the grid starting from a given point (row, col). Each of the four loops to walk contains the exact same code, a clear violation of DRY.

My solution is to write four loops and call a method in each. This is a throwaway method, so I used a Java 8 lambda with access to the grid & results structures because they are in lexical scope.

```
Predicate<int[]> countAndBreak = (int[] coord) -> {
    int r = coord[0];
    int c = coord[1];
    if (grid[r][c] == Grid.YUMMYCANDY)
        results.count++;
    if (grid[r][c] == Grid.WALL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

for (int r = row; r < grid.length; r++) {
    if (countAndBreak.test(new int[] { r, col }))
        break;
}
for (int r = row; r >= 0; r--) {
    if (countAndBreak.test(new int[] { r, col }))
        break;
}
for (int c = col; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
    if (countAndBreak.test(new int[] { row, c }))
        break;
}
for (int c = col; c >= 0; c--) {
    if (countAndBreak.test(new int[] { row, c }))
        break;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the solution for this quite yet, but I do know this kind of logic will become much easier with Java 9's `takeWhile`.

Comment: Since it's something that takes one parameter and returns a `boolean`, a `Predicate` is the appropriate functional interface to use. You can write `if (grid[r][c] == Grid.WALL) return true; else return false;` simply as `return grid[r][c] == Grid.WALL;`

Comment: Great catch on the boolean, @Jesper. Note that the only reason this predicate takes one parameter is that I fudged two parameters into one using an Array, a makeshift tuple for Java.

Comment: To avoid the arrays, you could have made your own functional interface with a method `boolean test(int row, int col)`.

Comment: You could use `BiPredicate<Integer,Integer>` alternatively, then you have to live with the boxing of the `int`s, but for the smaller indices that is very likely more efficient than the wrapping into an array. But creating your own functional interface isn’t so bad either…

Comment: Can one create the interface locally? I'm trying not to clutter my class structure.

Comment: You can create an `interface` as nested type, however, not within a method.

Answer (score 3):

Well, unless you create your own functional interface, you won’t get a better matching type. But the bigger obstacle in this context is the use of `int[]` rather than a dedicate point type. Staying with these types, the best you can get is like

```
Predicate<int[]> atWall  = coord -> grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] == Grid.WALL;
Predicate<int[]> isCandy = coord -> grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] == Grid.YUMMYCANDY;
int[] curr={ row, col};
results.count += countUntil(curr, p -> new int[]{ p[0]+1, p[1] }, atWall, isCandy);
results.count += countUntil(curr, p -> new int[]{ p[0]-1, p[1] }, atWall, isCandy);
results.count += countUntil(curr, p -> new int[]{ p[0], p[1]+1 }, atWall, isCandy);
results.count += countUntil(curr, p -> new int[]{ p[0], p[1]-1 }, atWall, isCandy);

…

static <T> int countUntil(
    T start, UnaryOperator<T> iterate, Predicate<T> until, Predicate<T> countable) {

    int[] holder={ 0 };
    Stream.iterate(start, iterate).anyMatch(element -> {
        if(until.test(element)) return true;
        if(countable.test(element)) holder[0]++;
        return false;
    });
    return holder[0];
}
```

abstracting the most flawed parts, i.e. when you decide to replace `int[]` by a dedicated coordinate type, you don’t have to change the `countUntil` method. On the other hand, the `countUntil` method hides the nasty use of mutable state which can be replaced by a clean solution when switching to [Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-), without the need to change the caller:

```
static <T> int countUntil(
    T start, UnaryOperator<T> iterate, Predicate<T> until, Predicate<T> countable) {

    return (int)Stream.iterate(start, until.negate(), iterate).filter(countable).count();
}
```

You can find other possible solutions, if you consider that the most interesting aspect is the abstraction of how to iterate from one location to the next, which allows to eliminate the code duplication by handling all four movements with the same code. Even a method using an ordinary loop could benefit from this.